# Program which takes input from a text file and returns a json string

Tags: java, json, filereader

Here is an example of my text file

```
JUNE 15
 Wednesday
BH 259: Trusting Jesus
TRUSTING GOD
Text: Hebrews 11:7-12

RBT: 1 Chron. 14-15;
John 18:19-40

By faith Abraham, when called to go to a place he would later
receive as his inheritance, obeyed and went, even though he
did not know where he was going. Hebrews 11:8 (NIV)
```

And output would be something like

```
JUNE 15\nWednesday\nBH 259: Trusting Jesus\nTRUSTING GOD\nText: Hebrews 11:7-12\n\nRBT: 1 Chron. 14-15;\nJohn 18:19-40\n
```

I tried reading file by read() on fileinputstream

```
in = new FileInputStream("2_jun.txt");
    out = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");

    int c;
    while((c = in.read()) != -1){
        out.write(c);
    }
```

but i am not able to compare End of line 
since i have to just replace EOL with "\n"

any suggestions as to how this can be achieved ?

Comment: `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` are adviced to read text from a file. You also have the `Files` class if you're using [tag:java-8]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you may want to use `Files#lines`.

It'll return a `Stream<String>` with each entry being a line of the file read.

Then you process them however you want.

```
String result;

try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("2_june.txt")){
    result = lines.map(x -> x + "\\n")
                  .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```